# Efficiently replacing pixel values in R,G,B planes python-openCV

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to replace the R,G and B values in python-OpenCV image with a given scalar value. I have the x and y co-ordinates for this replacement found using np.where(). I want these locations to be replaced by the given scalar values in the R,G and B plane each.
Currently, I am doing this:

```
    b=image[:,:,0]
    g=image[:,:,1]
    r=image[:,:,2]
    b[coords]=scalar1
    g[coords]=scalar2
    r[coords]=scalar3
    image[:,:,0]=b
    image[:,:,1]=g
    image[:,:,2]=r
```

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Try doing this:

```
image[coords] = np.array([scalar1,scalar2,scalar3])
```

`numpy` broadcasting FTW.  The spatial locations would be broadcasted over all of the slices and sets the first slice at each `(x,y)` location to `scalar1`, the next slice to `scalar2` at the same spatial locations, and finally `scalar3` for the last slice, same spatial locations.

Comment: Thanks.... As it turned out, simply `image[coords]=[scalar1,scalar2,scalar3]` did the job

Comment: @optimist - I was just about to correct myself.  Numpy broadcasting is awesome eh?